# Warping a contour to a perfect square Mat in Java OpenCV Android

Tags: java, android, opencv

I, like many before me, am trying to digitize a Sudoku board from an image. I have:

1. Gray-scaled, blurred and thresholded the image into a crisp, binary image
2. Identified the largest contour which correctly corresponds to the perimeter of the Sudoku board

However, if the paper is curved, the board's contour won't fit neatly into a boundingRect; its edges will be elliptical.

What I would really like is a way of taking some `MatOfPoint maxContour;`
and warping the corresponding region in the parent `Mat` to be a square, so that I can remove the board as a perfect square and manipulate it on its own.

However, ANY advice on getting the board or cells out of the image of Sudoku board are appreciated, I've played with Hough Transforms, the Sobel algorithm, and many other hare-brained schemes that have left me a little frazzled.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to first [get the Minimum bounding rectangle](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/bounding_rects_circles/bounding_rects_circles.html) of the rectangle represented by your sudoku corners which is effectively a perspectively transformed rectangle.

Then use the sudoku corners with the resulting rectangle corners to [warp the image](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html?highlight=warp%20perspective#warpperspective) (or just [warp the corners](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#perspectivetransform), whatever suits you), this will result in a straight image.